# node red send post request and using form-data

Tags: node-red, form-data

In my home assistant installation I use node red for all the logic and automation.
Now I want to play a sound on my speakers when someone is using the doorbell.

The speakers are connected to a raspberry with hifiberry amp and OS "r audio 1".

Now my problem:
To play the sound I have to call a http post request and send the data as form-data.

this is a working example in postman (this is what it generates me as POJO):

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("cmd", "sh");
formdata.append("sh[]", "cmd.sh");
formdata.append("sh[]", "mpcplayback");
formdata.append("sh[]", "play");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formdata,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://192.168.178.112/cmd.php?", requestOptions)
```

and this is the raw-request in postman

```
POST /cmd.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.30.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 9e45bb4d-652d-4817-9af9-332e58ea0fac
Host: 192.168.178.112
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------326296754220076880560686
Content-Length: 490
 
----------------------------326296754220076880560686
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cmd"
sh
----------------------------326296754220076880560686
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sh[]"
cmd.sh
----------------------------326296754220076880560686
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sh[]"
mpcplayback
----------------------------326296754220076880560686
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sh[]"
play
----------------------------326296754220076880560686--
 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.23.2
Date: Fri, 23 Dec 2022 22:43:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.2
```

Now I need to send this using node red and I just cant get it work.
Can someone show me how to send this request in node red with http-nodes?

best regards
Tobias

Comment: What have you tried with the http-request node? The help in the sidebar should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Having poked at this I don't think it's currently possible.

In theory passing the following `msg` object to the http-request node should work:

```json
{
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
  },
  payload: {
    cmd: 'sh':
    'sh[]': [
      'cmd.sh',
      'mpcplayback',
      'play'
    ]
  }
}
```

But when run it only adds one `sh[]` entry with `['cmd.sh', 'mpcplayback', 'play']` as the value.

I've raised a [Pull Request](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/pull/3991) to fix this as I believe this is incorrect.